# Avoid hiding Small App when opening keyboard

Tags: android, sdk, tablet, sony

I've just started to use the SmallApps API of Sony Tablet SDK. I need to show my small app always on the top but when user is opening the screen keyboard small app is making hidden. It possible to solve this problem?

Comment: Which device are you using this API on? Please state the software version too.

Comment: I'm using emulator with Sony Tablet SDK Add-on on API 15

Comment: Can you send a screenshot of the issue. I am trying to understand the procedure to reproduce it. Is it when you open keyboard for typing into small app that your small app gets hidden? Or when you open keyboard to type on an underlying app?

Comment: SmallApp hidding when i'm open keyboard on underlying application

Comment: I tried this on the emulator and couldn't reproduce the issue. do you have access to a device where you can check your app? I wasn't able to reproduce this issue.

Comment: @goncharov: There has been an update of the SDK you are using. I would like to ask you to update to the version found here http://developer.sonymobile.com/knowledge-base/sdks/sony-add-on-sdk/ and see if you still can replicate the issues.